# Multi line column comment in Hive using Hue

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I know how to add column comments in Hive using Hue. I specifically want the comment to be displayed on **several lines** in **Hue** when it is too long to be read on a single line.

I created a table I found in a previous stackoverflow post as an example :

```
 CREATE TABLE test_table(
   col1 INT COMMENT 'col1 one line comment',
   col2 STRING COMMENT 'col2 two lines comment',
   col3 STRING COMMENT 'col3 three lines comment',
   col4 STRING COMMENT 'col4 very long comment that is greater than 80 chars and is likely to spill into multiple lines',
   col5 STRING COMMENT 'col5 very long multi-line comment where each line is very long by itself and is likely to spill into multiple lines. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin in dolor nisl, sodales adipiscing tortor. Integer venenatis',
   col6 STRING COMMENT 'This comment has a very long single word ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvzxyz123 which will not fit in a line by itself for small column widths.',
   col7_NoComment STRING)
 COMMENT 'table comment two lines';
```

Here is the view of the table in Hue :

[image: View of the metadata of "table_test" in Hue]

As you can see, there is no line break for the comments. No matter how long the comment is, it is still added in a single line.

To break it into multiple lines in **Hue**, I thought about using the "\n" character. Here is the result with the query associated when modifying the comment of the column number 6 :

```
ALTER TABLE test_table CHANGE COLUMN col6 col6 STRING COMMENT 'This comment has a very long single word ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvzxyz123 \n Line break here because it will not fit in a single line.'
```

View of the metadata of "table_test" in Hue when trying to write a multi-line comment :

[image]

If you look at the line number 6, you cans see that what is supposed to be a comment is interpreted by **Hue** (or Hive) as a new column. So now instead of having my 7 columns, I have 8 columns.

Do you know if it is possible to have a multi-line comment for a column displayed in **Hue** ?

Comment: https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-4288 was reported and they pointed it might be a Hive issue.. please update that jira if you don't believe it's the case.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with defining multi-line comments.
This is only a display issue of the client tools (Hue, Hive CLI, Beeline etc).

#### Demo

```
create table mytable 
(
    mycol int comment 'Hello!
My name is Inigo Montoya!
You killed my father, prepare to die!'
)
```

**`show create table` looks fine**

```
show create table mytable 
;
```

---

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                         createtab_stmt                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| CREATE TABLE `mytable`(                                        |
|   `mycol` int COMMENT 'Hello!                                  |
| My name is Inigo Montoya!                                      |
| You killed my father, prepare to die!')                        |
| ROW FORMAT SERDE                                               |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'         |
| STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                                          |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'                   |
| OUTPUTFORMAT                                                   |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat' |
| LOCATION                                                       |
|   'file:/home/cloudera/local_db/mytable'                       |
| TBLPROPERTIES (                                                |
|   'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='{\"BASIC_STATS\":\"true\"}',        |
|   'numFiles'='0',                                              |
|   'numRows'='0',                                               |
|   'rawDataSize'='0',                                           |
|   'totalSize'='0',                                             |
|   'transient_lastDdlTime'='1498824282')                        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**The metastore looks fine**

```
select  c.*

from            metastore.DBS           d

        join    metastore.TBLS          t
        
        on      t.db_id = d.db_id
        
        join    metastore.SDS           s
        
        on      s.sd_id = t.sd_id
        
        join    metastore.COLUMNS_V2    c
        
        on      c.cd_id = s.cd_id
        
where   d.name     = 'local_db'
    and t.tbl_name = 'mytable'         
;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Dudu Markovitz for your quick response.

However, the problem is still here : 

when I create the table mytable woth your comment on several lines, the Hive Metastore through Hue displays it as if "My name is Inigo Montoya!" and "You killed my father, prepare to die!" were columns whereas these are just parts of the comment.

Comment: This is exactly what I said. This  a display issue of the client tools. The underlying data is stored correctly.

Comment: Yes  I realised it and tried to change my answer but I could not modify my comment. Sorry about that :)

Do you know how to fix this problem ?

Comment: I doubt if there is any